# 単著・共著　対 Single-author and multi-author

Tags: academic-japanese

## 背景

現在、私は色々な大学教員の就職活動をしています。前から、英語圏（特にアメリカ）と日本の著書を区別する方法は異なっていると思っていましたが、今まではあまり影響にならなかったから、聞いておりませんでした。

## 質問自体

学術冊は幾つの種類があるのですが、日本と英語圏の区別仕方は異なっているかどうか及びふさわしい表現を教えていただきたいです。

1. 一人は一人で一冊書く場合、英語に「single-authored book」、日本語に「単著」になるでしょうか。
2. 一冊は数名で書いて、各々章は違う人が書いてあて、英語に（書いたものの味方から）「single-authored book chapter」、日本語に「共著」の概念になるでしょうか。
3. 同じ章は数人に書いていた場合、「co-authors」と「共著」になるでしょうか。

私が気になるのは２の使い方。まず、上記は当てるかどうかを確認して欲しい。そして、一人で書いてあった章は「共著」と認めますか。それはその１冊は全員が協力したものと皆しているからか別の理由からそのように考えている。

## English

## Background

At present, I'm doing a lot of job applications for positions in Japanese universities. I've always felt the way that publications are classified differs between the English-speaking world (particularly America) and Japan, it has not had much impact on me until now so I hadn't asked earlier.

## The Question

There's a lot of types of academic books, and I'd like to know the correct way to use Japanese to describe some of my work.

1. A book written entirely by one person would be in English a "single-authored book" or a "単著" in Japanese right?
2. A book with chapters written by separate authors would be (for the authors) "single-author book chapters" in English and "共著" in Japanese?
3. If the same chapter is written by multiple people, then it's "co-authored" in English and "共著" in Japanese.

I'm particularly interested in 2. First, is my interpretation correct? Then, I'd like to better understand whether this is because the work is understood as a single book that everyone worked on or some other basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

３つともあっていると思います。

履歴書の業績の欄には、書籍の題名の後ろに、１番は`（単著）`、２番・３番は`（共著）`と書きます。

３番のように一つの章を数人で書いていて、（文系では３番はあまり見かけないですが、）自分の担当した部分が明確にできない場合は、`本人担当部分抽出不能/不可能`などと書きます。

２番は、自分が担当した章の番号とページも書きます。

一冊を数名で書いている場合は、一つの章を一人で書いていても、それが掲載されている書籍<sub>（大学の紀要や学会・研究会の論集などの雑誌を除く）</sub>は「共著」になります。